# Heatmap displaying magnitude and p-value (R::ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, gplots

I would like to make a heatmap that displays both magnitude and p-value of the number in each box. I want the color of each cell to describe the value (v) and I want the thickness of the border of each cell to describe the p-value.

```
df = data.frame(x=1:5, y=letters[1:5], v=1:5, p=10^(-(1:5)) )
```

What I have:

```
plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,fill=v)) + geom_tile()
```

I've got a first pass, this code changes the border thickness in correspondence with the significance of the value:

```
plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=v)) + 
                  geom_tile( size=1-df$p, colour='black' )
```

[image]

Now I'm just trying to clean up the figure. How can I add regular spacing between all cells? I need to create a buffer zone so the borders don't have overlap with neighboring cells?

> answer: height and width variables in aes

---

Here is the figure I end up with:

```
plt3 <- ggplot(mel, aes(y=Subject,x=HMO,fill=b,height=.75,width=.75 ))+ 
geom_tile(size=3*(mel$border)) + 
scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(c("blue1",'lightblue', "white" ,'orangered', "red1")) )
```

[image]

I need a legend for the borders but I cant get it to appear.  I think it is because it is not an aes.  Any idea of how I can get a legend for the border thickness?

Comment: Are you interested in thickness of border or tile thickness? You can control tile thickness with `width` argument in the tile geom. `plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,fill=v)) + geom_tile(width = df$p*10)`

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on border width not cell width. I included the code above.  Can you like the question so that I can post my figure? I'm pretty new to ggploting so I could use some help cleaning up the figure.

Comment: Sorry, i was paraphrasing.  I fixed it.

Comment: To reduce the tile size, add`h=0.95, w=0.95` (or whatever values work) inside `geom_tile`. The default is 1 for both `h` and `w`.

Comment: @eipi10 how can I get a legend to show up corresponding to the border thickness (detailed in the edited question above)

Comment: Can't test right now, but I think if you change to aes(size=3*border) then you'll get a legend.